# MySQL get next day & time combination

Tags: mysql, datetime

Using MySQL, how do I find the next weekday/time combination after a given datetime?

For example, how do I select the next Sunday at 10AM given an input date of Tuesday 12 August 2014 6PM - which should return: Sunday 17 August 10AM?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

Comment: This seems like a more appropriate task to do in code.  Not so much mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(@input_date, INTERVAL (8 - DAYOFWEEK(@input_date)) DAY) AS next_sunday
```

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/99-finding-next-monday-using-mysql-dates.html

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-08-12', INTERVAL 5 DAY) as NEXTSUNDAY;
```